# Telnet client control panel python

Tags: python, telnet, jasmin-sms

I am working on Jasmin SMS gateway and I want to use its CLI module using my python script. It serves this module as telnet. I am not sure ho to send and receive commands from telnet. I have tried telnetlib but I do not know how to use it properly. Jamsin SMS Gateway can be found here:

https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management/jcli/index.html#architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) library that works great with telnet and ssh clients. I can perform all the tasks of Jamsin's CLI module using my scripts.

There is also a web interface available written in Django and work perfectly with jasmin using pexpect. Its called [JasminWebPanel](https://github.com/tarikogut/JasminWebPanel).